# How to keep a dataframe loaded

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, module, load

In a jupyter notebook, is it possible to keep a big dataframe loaded accross the sessions after having imported it a first time?

My dataframe df is 2 000 000 rows.
I tried :

To create a module `mydata.py` containing the code `df=pd.read('myfile.csv')`. Then I executed in my notebook `from mydata.py import df` but df seems to be re-imported at each execution

The magic function `%store` df but it didn't work apparently because of memory.

Comment: try `df.to_pickle()` and load it then instead of csv. This should give you a huge speed advantage.

Comment: You could save it in a faster format: [Pandas Input/Output](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/io.html#input-output). Pickle, parquet, feather and hdf5 will all be faster than csv. If this is a single numeric type, you could even save raw binary data.

Comment: you can also improve performance quite a bit by casting types on import